# Changing target dynamically based on request

Tags: angular, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server

Is it possible in Angular CLI's `proxy.conf.js` to change the `target` field dynamically on a per request basis? From the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) I am aware that it's possible to change the path using the `bypass` function, but I need to change the **host** (i.e. target) based on the original path. For example:

- `/api/foo` => `https://foo.example.com`
- `/api/bar` => `https://bar.example.com`

Additionally, I would not like to create hard-coded rules for each API endpoint.

Comment: Is this for dev only..? The angular proxy is only for local development as far as I know..

Comment: Yes, it is for dev only.

Comment: Right. In that case.. I don’t think you can really do that logic on the proxy.conf (it’s just a json file after all).. maybe an interceptor is a possibility? You’d have to conditionally provide it so it only works in dev and gets disabled in prod..

Comment: Angular CLI actually also accepts a JavaScript file, not only a JSON file: https://angular.io/guide/build#proxy-multiple-entries
Having said that, I think you are correct about needing to embed a dev/prod logic in the app itself.

Comment: Oh cool, didn’t know that!